# Doubts with respect to a module maximum of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis, maxima-minima

I want to find the maximum of $$ f (z) = (z + 1) ^ 2 $$ In the triangular region composed by the points $ (0,0), (2,0), (0, i) $ of the complex plane, I know that this maximum is on the edge of the triangle by a theorem, but I must analyze three paths, when analyzing the path in which x and y vary simultaneously, huge accounts are appearing when I replace $ y = - \frac {x} {2} +1 $ in the expression, is there any easier way to parse through this path? Is this substitution valid?

Answer (score 0):

$|(z+1)^2|$ is the square of the distance from $-1$ to $z$.  So, which point of your triangle is farthest from $-1$?

Comment: Do you have any way you can do without that idea? The teacher will not accept this ...
Can I replace $ y = - \frac{x}{2} + 1 $ and calculate the maximum of what is right? Or do I need to parameterize the straight line from $ 2 to $ i $ as $ z (t) = 2 (1-t) + ti $ and   make $ x = (1-t), y = t $?
Which one is correct?